# error TS18022: A method cannot be named with a private identifier

Tags: typescript, methods, tsc

Running the `tsc` command outputs `error TS18022: A method cannot be named with a private identifier`, on removing `#` from methods everything works fine. I also tried this in vanilla javascript and it works!

Declaration of the private variable and method.

```
class someclass{
  #privatevar:string; //compiles
  constructor(props){
    this.#privatevar = props.string; //compiles
  }
  // gives error
  #privatemethod(){
  ...
  }
}
```

So, Is this only acceptable in Vanilla js or should I never declare private methods this way or am I missing something else? Frontend newbie here.

Comment: In what version? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#ecmascript-private-class-elements

Comment: @jonrsharpe tsc version 3.8.3, the target is es6 in tsconfig.

Comment: You'll need to upgrade to at least 4.3 to use that language feature. Also that's **not** ES6 syntax (it's not ES-anything yet, still at stage 3: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe upgrading the version solved the issue.